# Why image is converted to frequency domain

Tags: image-processing

In some filters of image processing, I see the image converted from spatial domain to frequency domain. My question is: why we do that? What is different between image in spatial domain and image in frequency domain ?

Answer (score 8):

This is usually only done for performance reasons. Filtering in the spatial domain is [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), which is `O(N^2)`, whereas in the frequency domain convolution becomes multiplication, which is `O(N)`. For small filters (small N) the cost of the FFT to/from the frequency domain is relatively large, and so filtering is performed directly, using convolution. However for larger filters (larger N), the balance tips in favour of filtering in the frequency domain, since the cost of the FFT becomes relatively small compared to the `O(N^2)` operation.

Comment: Also, certain filtering techniques are more intuitive in the frequency domain, such as removing regular lines and blurs. Just changing the average brightness of the images is as simple as modifying the center pixels of the image, depending on the FFT shift type used.